# ESC Control with PS3 Controller using Python

Tags: gpio, joystick

I have connected my PS3 controller to the raspberry pi using a bluetooth dongle. I am not sure about how to structure the code to control the ESC with the left joystick (axis 1). Could anyone advise me on tutorials or information which can aid the coding for this.

I want to structure the code in a way that 2 motors start up simultaneously with a single joystick input.

TJ

Comment: You need to focus on one step at a time and ask specific questions.  If you have problems with python, ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).  This isn't a discussion forum, so very vague/broad or open-ended questions aren't appropriate.  We expect you put in a minimum of effort yourself.  E.g., you should be able to find tutorials as easily as anyone else, and you know better than anyone what's appropriate for you.  If you then have a specific question about the material, that's fine.

Comment: You can use [triggerhappy](https://github.com/wertarbyte/triggerhappy) to map buttons on a controller to commands, however not axis...

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tutorials such as https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ which will help.

Just search for one you are happy with.